# Wildfly can't change css

Tags: css, xhtml, wildfly

Im currently working on a wildfly front end using xhtml and css. And no matter what I do to the css it doesn't change anything for me. For example if I delete all styles that my teammates did from previous commits, they're still there. There could be a red box and I delete it and its still there in my browser. Where does it get the information from? Im using intelij btw.

I tried everything in the css documents, but it works for everyone except for me. Even tried reinstalling the project.

Comment: WildFly does not render CSS, the browser does. This isn't a WildFly issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to download less data, browsers store static files like CSS localy.
You can clear this cash by deleting cookies of your app in your browser or by pressing `Ctrl + F5` (for most browsers).
You can also open a private instance of your browser and navigate to your website. Then when you want to clear the cash you can close and reopen a private window.